# Is it true that there is a non-negative eigenvector corresponding the largest eigenvalue for any non-negative adjacency matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a square matrix that is asymmetric and reducible (not strong connected), say $A$, which is an adjacency matrix (all the elements are either $0$ or $1$).

I am wondering if there is a similar conclusion like [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) that the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and the corresponding eigenvector would be non-negative (not all-zero vector).

Is it possible? If it is, how can I proof it? If not, what else requirements should be proposed?

Thank you.

Comment: @saulspatz, I edited my question, $A$ is an adjacency matrix.

Comment: The section titled "Applications" of the Wikipedia article you cited seems to address this question, but it isn't very clear to me.  Maybe it will give you someplace to start.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Non-negative_matrices) of the [Wikipedia page on the Perron-Frobenius Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).